# MSIX installation won't accept my digital certificate

Tags: ssl, installation, certificate, msix

I'm trying to create an MSIX installation for a small WPF desktop application. I don't need to publish to the store, just "sideloading".
I have a digital certificate, since MSIX requires one. I've installed the certificate on my machine, both for the Current User and the Local Machine.

1. When I click the "Choose Certificate" button, and then "select from store" the only certificate I see is the test certificate I created myself. I would expect to see "more options" or something like that which would allow me to choose whichever certificate I want.
2. When I click "Select from file", I get an error that says: "The manifest Designer could not import the certificate. The certificate you selected is not valid for signing because it is either expired or has another issue".

Initially, the "Issued To" value had a comma in it, which my research led me to believe would not work. So I had the certificate authority re-issue it without the comma. I got the same results.

Documentation is very sparse, but what I have seen indicates that I'm doing everything correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Geoff Callaghan